# Java android check if Acrobat Reader is installed if no download

Tags: java, android

I want to check if Acrobat Reader is installed when is not installed I want to open an android market on Adobe Acrobat Reader

This is how I check intalled :

```
public static boolean canDisplayPdf(Context context) 
{
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    testIntent.setType(MIME_TYPE_PDF);
    if (packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

next I when this method return false I want open an andrid market (apk) :

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
try
{
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=Adoba Acrobat Reader" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) 
{
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id= Adoba Acrobat Reader" + appPackageName)));
}
```

But open an android market it doen't work

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method to check for `Adobe Acrobat Reader` if its installed:

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, PackageManager packageManager) {
try {
    packageManager.getPackageInfo(packagename, 0);
    return true;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Usage:

```
boolean isAdobeInstalled = isPackageInstalled("com.adobe.reader", getPackageManager());
if (isAdobeInstalled) {
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader")));
}
```

Comment: If you found my answer helps you, please accept. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id= Adoba Acrobat Reader" + appPackageName)));
```

to

```
Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader)));
```